# Compiled libgphoto2 and gphoto2, but gphoto2 shows older libgphoto2

Tags: libgphoto2

I followed the basic directions (This reference gives how to deal with missing libraries: https://sourceforge.net/p/gphoto/mailman/message/33367636/) to compile the latest libgphoto2 and gphoto2 on a Raspberry Pi, but when I try seeing what is installed (gphoto2 -v), I get this:

```
This version of gphoto2 is using the following software versions and options:
gphoto2         2.5.23         gcc, popt(m), no exif, no cdk, no aa, no jpeg, no readline
libgphoto2      2.5.12         all camlibs, gcc, ltdl, EXIF
libgphoto2_port 0.12.0         gcc, ltdl, USB, serial without locking
```

The ./configure and make commands work OK.  When I do 'sudo make install', the script goes along (with some re-link warnings), but no errors.

The tail end of the 'sudo make install' is below.  What might be the cause of this?  Shouldn't I see 2.5.25 for libgphoto2?

```
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/udev'
 /usr/bin/install -c check-ptp-camera '/usr/local/lib/udev'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/libgphoto2'
  /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c print-camera-list '/usr/local/lib/libgphoto2'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/print-camera-list /usr/local/lib/libgphoto2/print-camera-list
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging/generic'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging/generic'
Making install in rpm
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging/rpm'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging/rpm'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging/rpm'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging/rpm'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/packaging'
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc'
Making install in api
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc/api'
Dummy target all-local.
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc/api'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
Dummy target install-data-local
Re-run configure with adequate parameters and run make again to build docs.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc/api'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc/api'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libgphoto2.3 libgphoto2_port.3 '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/doc'
Making install in gphoto-m4
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/gphoto-m4'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/gphoto-m4'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/gphoto-m4'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25/gphoto-m4'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c gphoto2-config '/usr/local/bin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/doc/libgphoto2'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 AUTHORS COPYING NEWS ABOUT-NLS ChangeLog README.md RELEASE-HOWTO.md README.packaging '/usr/local/share/doc/libgphoto2'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/gphoto2'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  gphoto2/gphoto2.h gphoto2/gphoto2-abilities-list.h gphoto2/gphoto2-camera.h gphoto2/gphoto2-context.h gphoto2/gphoto2-file.h gphoto2/gphoto2-filesys.h gphoto2/gphoto2-library.h gphoto2/gphoto2-list.h gphoto2/gphoto2-result.h gphoto2/gphoto2-setting.h gphoto2/gphoto2-version.h gphoto2/gphoto2-widget.h '/usr/local/include/gphoto2'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libgphoto2.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/libgphoto2-2.5.25'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a fresh Pi OS.

The solution comes in two steps.

1. set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH system variable

   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${libdir}/pkgconfig
2. add pi specific --libdir option to ./configure

   ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabih